# How to `wait` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a small Chrome Extension written in javascript with jQuery that should grab some data from a web page.
Target HTML looks like:

```
<div id="options">
  <div class="option"><div class="checkbox">1</div></div>
  <div class="option"><div class="checkbox">3</div></div>
  <div class="option"><div class="checkbox">5</div></div>
  <div class="option"><div class="checkbox">Other value</div></div>
  ...
</div>
<div id="result">0</div>
```

When any of `.checkbox` is checked `#result` will change. My task is to check `.checkbox` one by one and get `#result` for each.

```
var result = {};
// for each checkbox
$('#options .option').each(function(){
  // check it
  this.click()
  // wait a bit. Of course ideally if we can wait while #result is not changed but in practice sometimes checkbox doesn't change the result. So it will be enough to wait a few seconds
  // store data
  result[this.text()] = $('#result').text();
  // uncheck the checkbox
  this.click()
  // wait
});
console.log(result);
```

Any ideas how to wait correctly? 
Thanks

UPD: A little example that show my problem https://codepen.io/mihajlo-osadchij/pen/MNyazz

Comment: setTimeout will call a callback after a given wait - though there's far better ways to do what you want using event handlers

Comment: I believe you want to use an [event handler](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) instead of waiting for a bit to see if the checkbox was clicked on.

Comment: Why do you need to wait? Do you control the code that updates the value? If you do, you could fire a custom event or maybe you could listen to changes of the `#result` content itself and then check the values of the `option`. Could you give more details?

Answer (score 1):

As others are saying, you should use event handlers instead of doing a manual wait. Here is a basic example of how to bind a change event to get the value of the checkbox that has changed.

If you did use something like `setTimeout`, you would quite literally be purposefully slowing down your application due to bad design.

```js
$('.checkbox').on('change', (evt) => {
 console.log(evt.target.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2"  />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="3"  />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="4"  />
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get how can I use `event handler` in my case. Can you give me an example with my code?  My problem is not to wait while checkbox is changed but to wait while text in `#result` will be changed after checkbox pressed. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what it is you're trying to do. What IS clear is that you want event listeners/handlers to accomplish it. Are you programatically 'clicking' the checkboxes and trying to obtain the result from the programtic click?

Comment: Right you are, I need to obtain the result. I've made a little example https://codepen.io/mihajlo-osadchij/pen/MNyazz Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use an [event handler](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) instead of waiting for a bit to see if the checkbox was clicked on.

Since you are already using jQuery, it could be as simple like the demo below:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".checkbox").on('click', function(){
     $("#result").text( $(this).text());
  });
});
```

```css
.option{  
   width: 100px;
   height: 15px;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="options">
  <div class="option"><div class="checkbox">1</div></div>
  <div class="option"><div class="checkbox">3</div></div>
  <div class="option"><div class="checkbox">5</div></div>
  <div class="option"><div class="checkbox">Other value</div></div>  
</div>
Results: <span id="result">0</span>
```

Comment: Same question: I'm sorry but I can't get how can I use `event handler` in my case. Can you give me an example with my code?  My problem is not to wait while checkbox is changed but to wait while text in `#result` will be changed after checkbox pressed. Thanks.